# Mongoose find doesn't find from ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the same kind of thing in many other Models, but in this one is not working, does anybody can see a mistake?

Order schema:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;
var OrderItem    = require('./orderitem');

var OrderSchema  = new Schema({
    _account: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account', required: true},
    status: String,
    active: Boolean,
    comment: String,
    items: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OrderItem'}]
}, { timestamps: true });

OrderSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    console.log('order ID:', this._id);
    OrderItem.remove({_order: this._id}, next);
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
```

Order Item Schema:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var OrderItem = new Schema({
    _item: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item', required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    _account: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account', required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    _order: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order', required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    comment: String,
    quantity: {type: Number, required: '{PATH} is required!'}
}, { timestamps: true });

OrderItem.pre('validate', function (next) {
    var Item     = require('./item');
    var err;
    Item.findOne({_id: this._item, _account: this._account}, function (err, item) {
        if (err) next(err);

        if (!item) {
            err = new Error("Item does not exist");
            next(err);
        }
        next();
    });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('OrderItem', OrderItem);
```

The problem is when I try to remove the order, the middleware pre remove happens, the console.log shows the correct ID but the remove does not find anything (It was a find with item.remove() before with no results as well)

```
OrderSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    console.log('order ID:', this._id);
    OrderItem.remove({_order: this._id}, next);
});
```

If I do find without any filter, it gives me all the items, including the one with the specific order, but when I try to filter using the order ID (that is correct, I've checked) it always returns an empty array.

Thx

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(this._id)` inside the function? Bit of advice 1. move the `require()` "outside" of the function. The require system of nodejs does not work like you think, and you only need it in scope for the function assignment to middleware anyway. 2. Use `OrderItem.remove({ "_order": this._id},next)` instead, unless you actually need to trigger middleware on the "items" remove. Which is unlikely.

Comment: Thx @BlakesSeven , when I do `console.log(this._id)` I can see the ID I want to find. The require() was outside, I tried lots of things, and this is only the more simple example, in another part I need the find to do other things but remove and it is not working as well. Will try to change as you suggested and if it works will update to the other find problem (or create a new question)

Comment: `mongoose.set("debug",1)` Then you will see what is happening in the actual requests. Please use the "Model" form of `.remove()` rather than the instance method as was mentioned earlier, where possible. It's not only cleaner but there is less overhead due to a single request as opposed to many.

Comment: @blakesseven Thanks, I found the problem, actually there was no problem in my models, the problem was in my tests, I was running the tests in the wrong order, sorry about that, what should I do with the question? delete? answer with my stupid mistake? thanks so much

Comment: I got the mistake after enabling the debug mode, thx